# Solr Index PDF documents and post them to a remote server

Tags: curl, indexing, solr, apache-tika, pdftotext

Hi I am a naive user when it come to Solr. Please guide me on the following hurdles.

1) **Solr Index PDF documents**

**Solution tried**

I used tika-app 0.9.jar to extract the content from the Input PDF files to text file. Now I am trying to write a java code to index the documents to Solr.

2) **Post them to a remote server**

I need to post either the documents or the index to a central remote server. Can curl command be used for this.

Regards
Balaji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Solr Index PDF documents - I believe Solr does this for you.  [You can use Solr's http interface](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/content-extraction-tika) or [SolrJ](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/14/posting-rich-documents-to-apache-solr-using-solrj-and-solr-cell-apache-tika/).
2) Post the index to a remote server - [Solr replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) may fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the PDFs are on a web server, you can use Nutch to fetch and parse them, and then push the index to Solr via its HTTP interface.