# Solr open document after searching a keyword

Tags: solr, full-text-search, apache-tika, solr-cell

I am trying to index some PDF documents and then create a Search UI .

This question is somewhat related to

[Solr Index PDF documents and post them to a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482820/solr-index-pdf-documents-and-post-them-to-a-remote-server)

1) Indexing PDF Docs - > I use tika jar to convert PDF to text files and then use curl command to index them.

2) Search UI --> I m using **Solritas** browse feature and its built in UI.

**Objective :**

When I search for a word say "Lucene" in the list of indexed documents and when I get a result set for the given query I want a link to be displayed for each returned document and on clicking any document that I should be able to open that document.

**My current thoughts :**

I think I might have to change step one from a two way step to a single step of indexing them directly. I even think there should be an additional field in the schema.xml which tells about the location of these PDF docs.

Please guide me with some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

Comment: This is for point one rite. Indexing PDF docs. Related to point 2 any suggestions. Correct me if I am wrong with my interpretation.

Comment: I don't know much about Solritas so cannot help you with that.  However, if you are going to build your own UI, then you can store the filename as a separate field (see the `literal` parameter [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Literals)). It can then be used to construct the appropriate link in your UI.