# Solr display page no of PDF along with the results

Tags: solr, apache-tika

My question is just a continuation of this activity where I would like to display page no for the searched word in the input document.

[Solr open document after searching a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820895/solr-open-document-after-searching-a-keyword)

So I use

1) **tika-0.9.jar** to extract the output as an intermediate file.

2) Then I create another XML where the extracted output is the input and write the data in the format expected by Solr and then post this xml using **post.jar** command.

3) I use **Solritas Serach UI** with **Solr 3.2** version (http://localhost:8983/solr/browse) to view the results.

I would like to **display the page no's** along with the results.

**Example :**

If I search for a word test in the input PDF's what I have manged so far is to display all set of docs that contain this result and on click of any doc the input PDF will open. I would like to **display the page no** of the where this word say 'test' is present in each of the input doc.

Please give me some suggestion , like whether this can be done by some how storing the page no in the index .

Your suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks and regards.